# Azure DevOps Server 2019 Unable to load the service index for source from Azure Artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines

I am trying to restore the package from Azure Artifact (in Azure DevOps Server 2019) and getting the error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source http://xxxxx:8080/tfs/xxxxx/_packaging/xxxxx/nuget/v3/index.json.

This is my Nuget.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="xxxxx" value="http://xxxxx:8080/tfs/xxxxx/_packaging/xxxxx/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

I'm able to open the URL in the browser but not sure why it can't be restore by the command `dotnet restore`. I've try to reference to other in-house package and it's working with no issue.

xxxxx.csproj (Not Working on `dotnet restore`)

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="xxxxx.Database.Net60" Version="0.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="6.0.6" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

xxxxx.csproj (Working fine on `dotnet restore`, reference to other in-house package)

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="xxxxx.Core" Version="0.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="6.0.6" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Content of http://xxxxx:8080/tfs/xxxxx/_packaging/xxxxx/nuget/v3/index.json
[image]

Content of http://xxxxx:8080/tfs/xxxxx/_packaging/xxxxx/nuget/v3/flat2/xxxxx.database.net60/index.json
[image]

Comment: Did it work previously? How are you authenticating to the NuGet feed? Have you done any reading or looked at any of the documentation for Azure Artifacts?

Comment: It worked on other CI/CD on the same YAML template, but it was not working on this. I'm using the NuGetAuthenticate@1 task for the authentication. However, I managed to make it work now by switching to other Azure Artifacts endpoint and switching back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update the resolution that I've done to make this work.

1. Create a new Azure Artifacts feed and add the URL to the solution `Nuget.config`.
2. Upload the Nuget package into this new feed URL.
3. Add a Nuget service connection to this new feed URL.
4. Azure Pipelines able to build successfully.
5. Remove the new feed URL in `Nuget.config` for diagnosis of the existing issue.
6. Remove the newly added Nuget service connection.
7. Azure Pipelines can restore from the existing feed URL and build successfully.

The conclusion is still no idea what error caused the dotnet restore in the existing build is failed, I managed to get it to work by switching to a new feed URL and switching back.

### Update

After I released an updated core library version, the CI/CD pipeline broke again.

This is the original CI YAML, failure version 1.

```
    - task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
      inputs:
        nuGetServiceConnections: xxxxx
        forceReinstallCredentialProvider: true
      enabled: true

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'dotnet restore'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        feedsToUse: 'config'
        nugetConfigPath: 'NuGet.config'
        verbosityRestore: 'Detailed'
        noCache: true
      enabled: true
```

[image: Failure version 1]

Failure version 2. The credential doesn't even I've tried using PAT or Basic Authentication in Nuget service connection.

```
    - task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
      inputs:
        nuGetServiceConnections: xxxxx
        forceReinstallCredentialProvider: true
      enabled: true

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'custom'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        custom: 'restore'
        arguments: '--force --no-cache --verbosity Detailed'
      enabled: true
```

[image: Failure version 2]

Working version by changing to use `select` in `feedsToUse`, no longer using the Nuget.config

```
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'dotnet restore'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        feedsToUse: 'select'
        vstsFeed: '/xxxxxx'
        verbosityRestore: Normal
        noCache: true
      enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been having the same issue. A couple of times, in the verbose logs, I've noticed references to an "acquiring lock for the installation of...".  Using the `dotnet` custom command (just `run restore`) with the `--use-lock-file` argument seems to be doing the trick.

[image: Fix in build pipeline]

Comment: I don't have this error of "acquiring lock for the installation of..." but I managed to get it to work now by switching to another Azure Artifacts and switching back.